# How to get a 64 bit dll with c source file, def file, link file by using command line in vc 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit

My compile environment is windows xp and vc 6.0.

Now I have a c source file(msgRout.c), def file(msgRout.def), link file(msgRout.link), then I use commands below to get a 32 bit dll:

**1.cl /I ../include -c -W3 -Gs- -Z7 -Od -nologo -LD -D_X86_=1 -DWIN32 -D_WIN32 -D_MT -D_DLL msgRout.c**

**2.lib -out:msgRout.lib -def:msgRout.def -machine:i386**

**3.link /LIBPATH:../../Lib -nod -nologo -debug:full -dll @msgRout.link -out:msgRout.dll**

But the dll I got cannot be loaded on X64 application. it required a 64 bit dll.

So here is my question:
**Can I get a 64 bit dll with vc 6.0?
Using only above 3 commands alike, how can I get 64 bit dll?**

Many GREAT THANKS!!!

Allan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual C++ 6.0 does not include 64-bit compiler/libraries. You will need either a more recent version of Visual C++ or a Windows Platform SDK that has the 64-bit support. The earliest one is the [Windows Server 2003 Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a55b6b43-e24f-4ea3-a93e-40c0ec4f68e5&displaylang=en).

Once you have that installed, `cl /?` and `link /?` will have info on how to build 64-bit apps.

**Update:** If you have VS2005, you can build 64-bit binaries with the x86-amd64 cross-compiler (a 32-bit `cl.exe` that produces 64-bit code) or with the x64 compiler (a 64-bit `cl.exe`). To do that, you need to:

- Make sure you've installed the 64-bit tools support during VS installation.
- Open a command line and set it for x86-amd64 builds using `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\Vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64` or
- (on 64-bit Windows) Open an x64 command line and set it for 64-bit builds using `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\Vcvarsall.bat amd64`.

Once you do that, you should be able to use the same command line as above (with tcouple small changes - for `cl` you'll have to define /D:*X64*=1 or /D_AMD64_ and for `link` you'll have to change the `/machine:x86` to `/machine:x64`) to produce 64-bit version of your program.

Here are some links with more information:

[Installing Visual Studio 64-bit Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)
[HowTo: Enable a 64-Bit Visual C++ Toolset at the Command Line](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)
[Use Visual Studio to build 64-bit application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tolong/use-visual-studio-to-build-64-bit-application)
[64-bit Applications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)
[Seven Steps of Migrating a Program to a 64-bit System](https://web.archive.org/web/20100530053248/http://www.viva64.com:80/content/articles/64-bit-development/?f=64-bit-migration-7-steps.html)

Comment: Sorry, normally I'd give you exact cl/link command line, but I am on my iPhone right now w/o access to a PC.

Comment: Franci, could you provide exact cl, lib, link command line later, please? I got VS2005 (and VS2008) now, I think they could compile 64 bit dll? Thank you.

Comment: Your command is very helpful, you helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Microsoft does not have time machines.

Comment: You obviously are not aware of some of the latest MS Research projects... :-)